# Send message to a specific client socket (from NodeJS server to Java client)

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have a Java client and a NodeJS server that communicate via sockets. I want to have more clients connected at once using a Windows "cmd" for each one. My program should simulate some login/logout scenarios. What I want to achieve is:

- ClientA and ClientB both connect to Server
- ClientA logs in (using a command like "login username password")
- ClientB also logs in, but using the same username and password as ClientA
- ClientA should be logged out by force, while ClientB should log in successfully

I use a Java thread for each of the clients. My problem is that I don't understand how my NodeJS can send a message for each one of them to announce that they were logged in/logged out. The only one that receives the message is the last one who requested something from the server (i.e. the one who wants to log in).

`connection` is the current client-server connection. For every connection that has a successful login, I store the username in `currentUsername` key. I store all these successful logins in `connectionArray`. When a new client wants to log in, I go through all the connections to see if somebody is already logged in with that username:

**Node server**

```
var net = require('net')

var connectionArray = []

var server = net.createServer(function (connection) {

    connection.on('data', function (data) {

        let commandArray = data.toString().split(" ")

        if (commandArray[0] == "login") {

            for (let connectionElement of connectionArray) {
                if (connectionElement.currentUsername == requestedUsername) {
                    connectionElement.write(`We will log you out!\n`)
                    connection.write(`We will log you in!\n`)
                }
            }

            /* This Promise result is responsible for storing the connections
               I didn't yet treat the removing case of a logout */
            loginService.check(someParameters).then((response) => {
                connectionArray.push(connection)
            }, (rejected) => {
                connection.write(rejected.message)
            })
        }
    })
})
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ClientThread clientThread = new ClientThread();
        clientThread.start();
    }
}
```

**Login case inside ClientThread.java**

```
    case "login":
    try {
        if (splitCommand[1] != null && splitCommand[2] != null) {
            out.write(commandLine);
            out.flush();

            String line = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter your username and password!\n");
    }
    break;
```

The result will be that clientB will receive "We will log you in!", but clientA will not receive its message. What's the correct way to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If your problem is why clientA is NOT receiving "We will log you out" message, I suggest you to check if clientA is still connected before sending message.

Comment: Pleas provide [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help others to investigate further.

Comment: Sorry for that! I updated the post with the relevant code in Node and Java.